# Addition of two numbers in angularJS onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to add two numbers and want to display its result only when I click a button. Here is my code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<h2>Calculator</h2>

a: <input type="number" ng-model="a">
b: <input type="number" ng-model="b">
<button ng-click="addFunc()">Sum</button>
Sum : {{sum}}
<!-- <p><b>Summation:</b> {{sum = a + b}}</p> -->
<br/><br/><br/>
c: <input type="number" ng-model="c">
d: <input type="number" ng-model="d">
<p><b>Subtraction:</b> {{c - d}}</p>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.sum = 0;
    $scope.addFunc = function() {
        $scope.sum=a+b;
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$scope.sum = $scope.a + $scope.b;`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39015824/5137527

Comment: yeah...it worked..! thanks alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to access `a` and `b` from this function, it will look into the *lexical scope* of this function. Since you don't have the variables declared over there it won't work. You neither have the variables declared anywhere up in the scope chain as its inside the custom `$scope`*(just a javascript Object)* maintained by angular. Angular uses its own `$scope` which is injected into the controller, to access that scope you have to access via `$scope.` itself. The idea is to share this between template(view) and function(controller)

```
$scope.addFunc = function() {
    $scope.sum=a+b;
}
```

In your template `a + b` works because angular uses `$scope` internally for all variables used in your template, so you don't have to add `$scope` over there.

```
<p><b>Summation:</b> {{sum = a + b}}</p>
```

In your case you can use `$scope` like:

```
$scope.addFunc = function() {
    $scope.sum= $scope.a + $scope.b;
}
```

or use `this` as the function is called with `$scope` and will have implicit reference.

```
$scope.addFunc = function() {
    this.sum= this.a + this.b; //when calling $scope.addFunc() this will be $scope
}
```

or use `with` statement (although not recommended due to some edge cases)

```
$scope.addFunc = function() {
    with($scope) sum = a + b;
}
```

Comment: Your knowledge is amazing...thanks for this accurate explanation

Answer (score 1):

The moment you wrote a & b as ng-model, They are automatically connected to $scope object.

So if you want to add them, you simply have to write

```
$scope.a + $scope.b
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the values to controller

```
<button ng-click="addFunc(a, b)">Sum</button>
```

controler

```
$scope.addFunc = function(a, b) {
    $scope.sum=a+b;
}
```

**OR**

HTML:

```
<button ng-click="addFunc()">Sum</button>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.addFunc = function() {
    $scope.sum=$scope.a+$scope.b;
}
```

Comment: @Pradeep can you pls approve my answer

Comment: I accept/approve your answer. If there is any official way to accept/approve answer, please let me know as I am new to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this code
```

### Calculator

```
a: <input type="number" ng-model="a">
b: <input type="number" ng-model="b">
<button ng-click="addFunc()">Sum</button>
Sum : {{sum}}
<!-- <p><b>Summation:</b> {{sum = a + b}}</p> -->
<br/><br/><br/>
c: <input type="number" ng-model="c">
d: <input type="number" ng-model="d">
<p><b>Subtraction:</b> {{c - d}}</p>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.sum = 0;
    $scope.addFunc = function() {
        $scope.sum=$scope.a+$scope.b;
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I accept/approve your answer. If there is any official way to accept/approve answer, please let me know as I am new to it.

Answer (score 0):

`a` and `b` are in `$scope`:

```
$scope.addFunc = function() {
    $scope.sum = $scope.a + $scope.b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/8444/)

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
    $scope.sum = 0;
    $scope.addFunc = function() {
        $scope.sum=$scope.a+$scope.b;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code: We need to type cast our variable i.e., ng-model value to number else it will return string.

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="myctrl">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js"> </script> 
    
    <script>
        var app=angular.module("MyApp",[]);
        app.controller("myctrl",function($scope){
            $scope.value=0;
            $scope.add=function(){
            $scope.value=Number($scope.fnum)+   Number($scope.snum);
            };
            
        });
    </script>

    firstname:<input type="text" ng-model="fnum" placeholder="Enter value" /><br>
    lastname:<input type="text" ng-model="snum" placeholder="Enter value" /><br>
    <input type="button" value="Click" ng-click="add() " /><br>
    <div ng-repeat="a in res()">{{a}}</div>
    <div>{{value}}</div>
</body>
</html>
```